# how to restrict a user to access the file

Tags: acl

I have created a file which resides inside my directory on a unix server.
People have sudo privileges.
How can I restrict them to read that file (even when they have sudo previleges) ?

Comment: If they have sudo priveleges then they can just change to you anyway.

Comment: giving sudo to the users is giving the keys  to the kingdom. Unless you are using a 3rd party privilege broker application, which acts as a wrapper around what seems to be the root account, what you are trying to do is impossible with the standard UNIX operation. root user is meant to be the absolute power to do anything, in the case of an administrative need. But today, unfortunately it is being used to _fix_ problems created by sloppy coding.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the `sudoers` file?

Comment: You could always use `sudo chattr +i file` and hope that none of them know how to undo it.

Comment: @PaulCalabro Yes I do have access to sudoers file... but please do not ask me to remove other users' id from this :)

Comment: @User112638726 : can you please explain this chattr thing

Comment: Sets the file to immutable, so pretty much read only, even root can't edit it unless you remove the attribute.

Comment: In your sudoer file you can specify what identity and what kind of program your users can use. Perhaps you can restrict their access. Did they really need root permissions ?

Answer (score 2):

Providing `sudo` access does not have to equate to:

> giving the keys to the kingdom.

Just don't be so generous with your `sudoers` permissions.
If you want them to just have access to read a file, provide only `sudo` access to `cat`.

Also, be careful of granting `sudo` access to apps like `vim` or `less`, which allow you to drop into a shell (as root).

Comment: Actually one can get root shell form `less` as easy as from `vim`

Comment: Interesting! How do you shell escape in `less`?

Comment: `:!vi` - moves you to `vi`, the rest of way is known to you :)

Comment: Whoa! Just tried it. Did not know about! [spine chill] Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

SELinux would be a way to do this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux

By definition, root has access to everything, so you won't have much luck otherwise, I'm afraid.